# Batch file to copy and rename files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, xcopy, robocopy

I need a batch file that:

1. Copies all items (directories and subdirectories) from `folder a` to `folder b`
2. If I overwrite a file name/folder in `folder a` then it will correctly rename file/folder in `folder b`

I have accomplished the first task:

```
@echo off
xcopy "D:\...\abc\*.*" "D:\...\def" /E 
pause
```

Above copies all the content in the folder to by destination folder i.e.

```
Folder a: 
    -folder1, folder2
    -fileA, fileB
```

Is correctly present in `folder b`. However, if I rename a file in `folder a` and run the script:

```
rename folder1 -> folder0
```

Then this is how file structure looks:

```
Folder b:
    -folder1, folder2, folder0
    -fileA, fileB
```

I want folder1 to be renamed to folder0, how do I do this?

I could overwrite everything (not sure how with xcopy) but is there another solution to this?

I've looked at the various [flags](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268), but can't find what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want it `robocopy`

You can mirror your `folderA` to `folderB` on execution of this batch file:

```
robocopy "D:\...\abc" "D:\...\def" /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5
```

A great tutorial can be found [here](http://improve.dk/simple-file-synchronization-using-robocopy/), explaining the various params